# Installing a Java service on Windows 7 with NSSM

Tags: java, windows-services, inno-setup, nssm

I am trying to use Inno Setup to install a Windows service as a JAR file running under NSSM (Non-Sucking Service Manager)

```
nssm install JarService java -jar service.jar
nssm start JarService
```

ends up putting my service in the "Paused" state, and it doesn't ever seem to get started.

Since the location of `java.exe` can change with updates, I want to be able to run the service without having the explicit path to `java.exe`, how can I launch the java service without an explicit path in NSSM?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had to do something quite similar just last week.
When I replace "java" with the full path to java.exe, I can get a service to run, so:

```
nssm install JarService FullPath/java.exe -jar service.jar
```

should work.  I don't think NSSM searches the path for its application.

Comment: getting the error when I start the service "windows could not start the service, if its a non Microsoft service refer to service specific error code 3"

Comment: I am also getting the same , any solutions how to resolve it

Answer (score 2):

On Windows 2012 R2 OS, I used:

```
nssm install MyServiceName "C:\Program Files\MyServiceName\start.bat"
```

Then in the batch file, start.bat, I have:

```
java -cp "C:\Program Files\MyServiceName\MyServiceName.jar" com.package.MyServiceMainClass
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to create a powershell script to run the java service:

```
java.exe -jar service.jar
```

Then, I reference the full path to powershell in Inno Setup's [Run] section:

```
Filename: "{app}\nssm.exe"; Parameters: "install ""{#MyAppName}"" ""{sys}\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"" ""-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File {app}\runservice.ps1"""; Flags: runhidden
```

As long as powershell doesn't move, this should work.